# Fetch with retry, abort, etc

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I've been trying to find a wrapper that does fetch with retries, timeouts, aborts, etc.  I came across https://pastebin.com/54Ct4xEh a little bit ago, and after fixing a couple typos (missing `options.` and `=>`), it works, except... well, maybe it works, but I don't know how to use it.  How do I abort a fetch with this particular wrapper?  I have a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/1fdwb2o6/2/.  With this code, how can I, say, click a button and have it abort this fetch loop?  For my use case, I' using boopstrap, and I have a modal that, when shown, attempts to load dynamic content.  If the user clicks Cancel while it's loading, I want the fetch process to stop.  From what I can tell, I should be able to do it with the code below... but I'm not sure how to perform the abort.  Perhaps this isn't possible, as structured, with a Promise... but I don't know enough (anything) about promises to know better, one way or the other.

```
const fetchWithRetry = (userOptions) => {
  let abort = false;
  const options = {
    url: '',
    options: {},
    cancel: {},
    retries: 5,
    retryDelay: 1000,
    ...userOptions
  };

  // Add an abort to the cancel object.
  options.cancel.abort = () => {
    abort = true;
  };


  // Abort or proceed?
  return abort ? Promise.reject('aborted') : fetch(options.url).then(response => {

    // Reject because of abort
    return abort ? Promise.reject('aborted')

      // Response is good 
      : response.ok ? Promise.resolve(response.text())

      // Retries exceeded
      : !options.retries ? Promise.reject('retries exceeded')

      // Retry with one less retry
      : new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // We use the returned promise's resolve and reject as
          // callback so that the nested call propagates backwards.
          fetchWithRetry({
            ...options,
            retries: options.retries - 1
          }).then(resolve, reject);
        }, options.retryDelay);
      });
  });
}

var xxx;
console.clear();

xxx = fetchWithRetry({
    url: "some_file_that_doesnt_exist.php"
  })
  .then((response) => {
    alert(response);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error: response error, request timeout or runtime error
    alert("Error!  Cannot load folder list!  Please try again!");
  });

setTimeout(function() {
  // somehow, abort the fetch...
  // xxx.abort(); <-- no worky...
}, 1234);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: I don't see how this code can possibly work.  There is no way for the caller to call some `cancel` function that `fetchWithRetry()` can actually use.  For this to work using this architecture, the internals of `fetchWithRetry()` have to return to the caller a cancel function that the caller can call when they want to cancel the retry process.  As written, this function just returns a promise and nothing else.  So, the caller has nothing they can call to cancel.  It creates a cancel function internally, but the caller never has access to that.

Comment: Ok, appreciate the comment.  I will definitely look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments, the code you have in your question does not provide a `cancel()` function that the caller can use.  It has a `cancel()` function internally, but that's not something the caller can use.  As written that function just returns a promise so the caller has nothing they can call to cancel the retries.

So, I decided to write my own version of `fetchWithRetry()` that would work for your use case.  This has a number of capabilities that the one in your question does not:

1. It returns both the promise and a cancel function so the caller can cancel the retries.
2. It allows you to pass the `init` options for `fetch()` so you can pass any of the various arguments that `fetch()` supports and are often needed such as `withCredentials`.
3. It has an option to check the `response.ok` boolean so it will detect and retry more things that you would if you required the promise to be rejected before a retry (note: `fetch()` doesn't reject on a 404, for example).
4. If There was a `fetch()` rejection and it was either cancelled or it ran out of retries, then it will use the newest `Error` class feature where it will set the `cause` to the actual `fetch()` error so the caller can see what the original error was.

Note that this version of `fetchWithRetry()` returns an object containing both a promise and a cancel function.  The caller uses the promise the same way they would any promise from `fetch()` and they can use the `cancel()` function to cancel any further retries.

Here's the code:

```
const Deferred = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof Deferred)) {
        return new Deferred();
    }
    const p = this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.resolve = resolve;
        this.reject = reject;
    });
    this.then = p.then.bind(p);
    this.catch = p.catch.bind(p);
    if (p.finally) {
        this.finally = p.finally.bind(p);
    }
}

function fetchWithRetry(url, userOptions = {}, init = {}) {
    const options = {
        // default options values, can be overridden by userOptions
        retries: 3,
        retryDelay: 1000,
        checkResponseOk: true,
        ...userOptions
    };

    let cancelled = false;
    let timerDeferred;
    let timer;

    function run() {
        return fetch(url, init).then(response => {
            // force retry on non 2xx responses too
            if (options.checkResponseOk && !response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`fetch failed with status ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response;
        }).catch(err => {
            // got error, set up retry
            console.log(err);
            if (cancelled) {
                throw new Error("fetch cancelled", { cause: err });
            }
            --options.retries;
            if (options.retries < 0) {
                throw new Error("fetch max retries exceeded", { cause: err });
            }

            // create new Deferred object for use with our timer
            // so it can be resolved by the timer or rejected
            // by the cancel callback
            timerDeferred = new Deferred();

            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                timerDeferred.resolve();
                timer = null;
            }, options.retryDelay);

            return timerDeferred.then(() => {
                if (cancelled) {
                    throw new Error("fetch cancelled", { cause: err });
                }
                return run();
            });
        });
    }

    return {
        promise: run(),
        cancel: () => {
            cancelled = true;
            // if currently in a timer waiting, reject immediately
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            if (timerDeferred) {
                timerDeferred.reject(new Error("fetch cancelled"));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Sample usage:

```
const result = fetchWithRetry(someUrl);

result.promise.then(resp => {
    return resp.text().then(data => {
        // got final result here
        console.log(data.slice(0, 100));
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

// simulate user cancel after 1.5 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
    result.cancel();
}, 1500);
```